# Why does it say ORA-14006: invalid partition name?

Tags: oracle, ddl, database-partitioning

I used this code on Oracle PL/SQL on version 13

```
 ALTER TABLE instrument_balance_hist MODIFY  PARTITION BY RANGE( instrument_id )  INTERVAL (100)(
partition p1 VALUE LESS THAN (100),
partition p2 VALUE LESS THAN (200),
partition p3 VALUE LESS THAN (300),
partition p4 VALUE LESS THAN (400),
partition p5 VALUE LESS THAN (500),
partition p6 VALUE LESS THAN (600)
);
```

The data type of instrument_id is number(6).

It keeps saying invalid partition name and gives a red underline at 'BY'.

Comment: Also, there is no version 13 of Oracle.  There is Oracle 12c.  And Oracle 19c.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  
I have corrected the code. Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. the pl/sql developer version is 13.

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language, PL/SQL Developer is a desktop development tool. Neither is related to the issue though. What matters is your Oracle version.

Answer (score 2):

[Converting a Non-Partitioned Table to a Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5) requires Oracle 12.2 or later. Also, it's `VALUES`, not `VALUE`.

```
create table instrument_balance_hist (instrument_id, somecol) as
select 100, 'Kittens' from dual union all
select 200, 'Puppies' from dual;
```

```
alter table instrument_balance_hist
modify partition by range (instrument_id) interval (100)(
partition p1 values less than (100),
partition p2 values less than (200),
partition p3 values less than (300),
partition p4 values less than (400),
partition p5 values less than (500),
partition p6 values less than (600)
);
```

```
with function highval(t varchar2, p varchar2) return varchar2 as
         hv varchar2(4000);
     begin
         select high_value into hv
         from   user_tab_partitions
         where  table_name = t
         and    partition_name = p;
       
         return hv;
     end highval;
select partition_name
     , highval(p.table_name, p.partition_name) as high_value
from   user_tab_partitions p
where  p.table_name = 'INSTRUMENT_BALANCE_HIST'
/
PARTITION_NAME HIGH_VALUE
-------------- ----------------
P1             100
P2             200
P3             300
P4             400
P5             500
P6             600

6 rows selected
```